# Certain lines of code not executing in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a simple calculator using tkinter, but with my add() function, it is not changing the value of the operator variable and it is not fetching the value for number1. It is strange to me because the e.delete command works fine in the add() function. Thanks in advance for the help. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import*

def one():
    e.insert(END, '1')
def add():
    operator = 1
    number1=int(e.get())
    e.delete(0,END)
def equal():
    number2=int(e.get())
    if (operator==1):
        result=int(number1+number2)
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(END,result)

win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x300')
win.title('Calculator')
operator = int(0)
e = Entry(win, width=25)
e.grid(column=1, row=0)
Btn1= Button(win, text='1', command=one, height=2, width=4)
Btn1.grid(column=1, row=1)
addBtn= Button(win, text='+', command=add, height=1, width=2)
addBtn.grid(column=4, row=1)
equalBtn= Button(win, text='=', command=equal, height=1, width=2)
equalBtn.grid(column=4, row=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the `add()` function, the value of `number1` is never used...

Comment: is number1 global variable or local variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the *scope* of your variables.  In Python it's possible to ensure the code is dealing with a variable as a global variable by using the `global` keyword.  Otherwise the scope of the variable is just to that function - meaning it has only a local scope, making it a *local variable* - thus it exists only inside that function.  Python does it's best to automatically determine what's local and what's global, but using the `global` keyword ensures it.

So it looks like your `number1` variable only ever had local scope.  This version works for me.  I am able to add `1` with `11` to get `12`.

```
from tkinter import*

number1  = 0
number2  = 0
operator = 0

def one():
    global e
    e.insert(END, '1')

def add():
    global e, operator, number1
    operator = 1
    number1  = int(e.get())
    e.delete(0,END)

def equal():
    global e, operator, number1, number2
    number2 = int(e.get())
    if (operator == 1):
        result = int(number1+number2)
        e.delete(0,END)
        e.insert(END,result)

win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x300')
win.title('Calculator')
e = Entry(win, width=25)
e.grid(column=1, row=0)
Btn1= Button(win, text='1', command=one, height=2, width=4)
Btn1.grid(column=1, row=1)
addBtn= Button(win, text='+', command=add, height=1, width=2)
addBtn.grid(column=4, row=1)
equalBtn= Button(win, text='=', command=equal, height=1, width=2)
equalBtn.grid(column=4, row=2)

win.mainloop()
```

By the way: Your buttons didn't appear in the window for me until it was maximised.  Maybe that grid layout is a little wrong, or the window too small.

Also whenever you use the `int()` converter on a string, there's a very real chance it will fail (like whenever the `e` entry is empty).  It's a good practice to handle all these errors. Perhaps write a single function to check the input and handle errors, using that instead of `int()`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to declare some of your function variables as global so they are referring to the same thing. Normally the variables will be scoped to the function they're in.

```
def add():
    global operator
    operator = 1
    ...
```